# Custom text field with padding, top vertical alignment, multiline placeholder text

Tags: swift, uitextfield, textfield, text-alignment

[image]

I want to make custom text field which has left right bottom top padding. So I use below code to achieve that:

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField {

let padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 8, bottom: 8, right: 8);

override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return bounds.inset(by: padding)
}

override func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return bounds.inset(by: padding)
}

override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return bounds.inset(by: padding)
} }
```

I also want to make the placeholder text alignment to be on top instead of at the centre of the TF. I use below code:

```
 textField.contentVerticalAlignment = .top
```

However, when I tried to set the vertical alignment with padding, the alignment won't work. When I remove the padding, only then it will work. What I meant here is, it will only work either one. How can I achieve both of them? Plus, is it possible to show multiline placeholder text instead of showing it in one line with the dots at the end?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `placeholderRect(forBounds:)`, like so

```
override func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    var placeholderPadding = self.padding
    placeholderPadding.top = 0

    var rect = bounds.inset(by: placeholderPadding)

    // We need to adjust placeholder in-case there is a leftView or rightView
    if rightViewMode == .always || rightViewMode == .unlessEditing, let rightViewWidth = self.rightView?.frame.width {
        rect.size.width -= rightViewWidth
    }

    if leftViewMode == .always || leftViewMode == .unlessEditing, let leftViewWidth = self.leftView?.frame.width {
        rect.size.width -= leftViewWidth
    }

    return rect
}
```

Question-2: `UITextField` works only on 1 line, you need to have a look at `UITextView` for this

Comment: may I know what is the condition for if { ... } for the rightViewMode & leftViewMode? because it shows error when there is no condition for that

Comment: typo, i got rid of this

Comment: not working, still the same like in the screenshot I show above. btw thank you for your answer. I think I need to change it to text view since I need more than 1 line text.

Answer (score 0):

for the first question you may extend UIView
    public extension UIView {

```
/// SwifterSwift: Border color of view; also inspectable from Storyboard.
@IBInspectable public var borderColor: UIColor? {
    get {
        guard let color = layer.borderColor else { return nil }
        return UIColor(cgColor: color)
    }
    set {
        guard let color = newValue else {
            layer.borderColor = nil
            return
        }
        // Fix React-Native conflict issue
        guard String(describing: type(of: color)) != "__NSCFType" else { return }
        layer.borderColor = color.cgColor
    }
}

/// SwifterSwift: Border width of view; also inspectable from Storyboard.
@IBInspectable public var borderWidth: CGFloat {
    get {
        return layer.borderWidth
    }
    set {
        layer.borderWidth = newValue
    }
}

/// SwifterSwift: Corner radius of view; also inspectable from Storyboard.
@IBInspectable public var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
    get {
        return layer.cornerRadius
    }
    set {
        layer.masksToBounds = true
        layer.cornerRadius = abs(CGFloat(Int(newValue * 100)) / 100)
    }
}

/// SwifterSwift: Height of view.
public var height: CGFloat {
    get {
        return frame.size.height
    }
    set {
        frame.size.height = newValue
    }
}

/// SwifterSwift: Check if view is in RTL format.
public var isRightToLeft: Bool {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *, tvOS 10.0, *) {
        return effectiveUserInterfaceLayoutDirection == .rightToLeft
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

/// SwifterSwift: Take screenshot of view (if applicable).
public var screenshot: UIImage? {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, false, 0)
    defer {
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }
    layer.render(in: context)
    return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
}

/// SwifterSwift: Shadow color of view; also inspectable from Storyboard.
@IBInspectable public var shadowColor: UIColor? {
    get {
        guard let color = layer.shadowColor else { return nil }
        return UIColor(cgColor: color)
    }
    set {
        layer.shadowColor = newValue?.cgColor
    }
}

/// SwifterSwift: Shadow offset of view; also inspectable from Storyboard.
@IBInspectable public var shadowOffset: CGSize {
    get {
        return layer.shadowOffset
    }
    set {
        layer.shadowOffset = newValue
    }
}

/// SwifterSwift: Shadow opacity of view; also inspectable from Storyboard.
@IBInspectable public var shadowOpacity: Float {
    get {
        return layer.shadowOpacity
    }
    set {
        layer.shadowOpacity = newValue
    }
}

/// SwifterSwift: Shadow radius of view; also inspectable from Storyboard.
@IBInspectable public var shadowRadius: CGFloat {
    get {
        return layer.shadowRadius
    }
    set {
        layer.shadowRadius = newValue
    }
}

/// SwifterSwift: Size of view.
public var size: CGSize {
    get {
        return frame.size
    }
    set {
        width = newValue.width
        height = newValue.height
    }
}

/// SwifterSwift: Get view's parent view controller
public var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
    weak var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self
    while parentResponder != nil {
        parentResponder = parentResponder!.next
        if let viewController = parentResponder as? UIViewController {
            return viewController
        }
    }
    return nil
}

/// SwifterSwift: Width of view.
public var width: CGFloat {
    get {
        return frame.size.width
    }
    set {
        frame.size.width = newValue
    }
}

// swiftlint:disable next identifier_name
/// SwifterSwift: x origin of view.
public var x: CGFloat {
    get {
        return frame.origin.x
    }
    set {
        frame.origin.x = newValue
    }
}

// swiftlint:disable next identifier_name
/// SwifterSwift: y origin of view.
public var y: CGFloat {
    get {
        return frame.origin.y
    }
    set {
        frame.origin.y = newValue
    }
}}
```

this will give you those features in attribute inspector

[image]

for the second question, UITextField is only one line so try to use UITextView